# Image URI won't load when using setState

Tags: react-native

My `<Image/>` remains blank even though I am console logging the URI value.

I am getting the URI from an API. The URI I'm getting is definitely https as well.

My code looks like this:

```javascript
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        img: ''
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getImage(this.props.id)
}

getImage(id){
    _this = this;
    fetch(`someURL${userId}`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        _this.setState({
            img: responseJson.pic_url,
        });
    });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.img) {
        return (
            <Image 
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={{height: 50, width: 50}}
                source={{uri: this.state.img}}
            />
    }
    return( 
        <View/>
    )
}
```

If I just put the link into the URI directly like `source={{uri: 'https://my-link'}}` it works. I need to be able to use state though b/c the link is coming from my api.

Comment: can you log `this.state.img` in the render method? Also you have a typo in your image style. It should be height and not heigh.

Comment: @D-reaper yes I am logging it inside the render method and it comes up. I don't have those typos in my actual code either

Comment: Does the parent component have dimensions? Can you actually see that it is being rendered? One way of checking this is by setting it a contrasting background color. The contrast will also reveal if your image is rendered or not

Comment: @D-reaper if I hard code the url in it shows up. If I replace the Image component with a Text Component the url string displays aswell

Comment: Here is an expo snack that implements image: https://snack.expo.io/S1v59G_m-. The url from the API is http, so I had to change it to https to make it work. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: You are supposed to `await` for the image to be ready, then to set it as the source, then to render. And why Component**Did**Mount? which gets called after render. You need Component**Will**Mount (to prepare before render)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/) with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imageUri: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const _this = this
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        _this.setState({
          imageUri: json.url.replace('http', 'https')
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Image Test!
        </Text>
        {
          this.state.imageUri ? (
            <Image 
              resizeMode="cover" 
              source={{uri: this.state.imageUri}} 
              style={{height: 200, width: 200}}
            />
          ) : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

And it works just fine. The url that I get from the API is http, so I had to change it to https because it wouldn't work otherwise. Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: could you help me understand why the this.state.imageUri ? (... ) : null } works or was necessary ? it resolved my issue with the uri cannot be an empty string and I would like to understand why that is

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
source={uri: this.state.img}
```

with

```
source={{uri: this.state.img}} // it will work if path is proper
```

Comment: I actually have it like this already `source={{uri: this.state.img}} `but  it still blank. It kinda looks like the space for the image is there though. Just not showing up

Comment: Can you please try by removing `resizeMode="cover"`

Comment: If I hard code the url I am getting from the API it shows. Removing cover didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So you are actually getting the response from your API? Did you print your URL inside your fetch method?

You don't need _this = this; as arrow functions are already binding this. However I think it shouldn't be a problem.

You have a mistake in your fetch.then 
It should be:

```
.then( (response) => response.json())
```

You missed the brackets around response

Comment: I'm getting a response from the API and my state variable is being state the way I need it too. Nothing wrong with the fetch. Parenthesis around the response isn't needed either. I have a linter that automatically removes it.

Comment: can you reformat your render code like this?

render() {
const imageView = this.state.img? <Image 
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={{height: 50, width: 50}}
                source={{uri: this.state.img}}
            />:
<View/>;
 return (
  <View> {imageView} </View>
    );  
}

Comment: `render() {
const imageView = this.state.img? <Image 
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={{height: 50, width: 50}}
                source={{uri: this.state.img}}
            />:
<View/>;
 return (
  <View> {imageView} </View>
    );  
}`