# why react native can't require image currently?

Tags: react-native

```
<Image source={require(rowData.avatar)} />
```

error : Unknown name module ‘xxxxxx’

Why can print out the path but can't read pictures？

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Error: Unknown named module', loading react-native image from a dynamic path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713025/error-unknown-named-module-loading-react-native-image-from-a-dynamic-path)

Comment: Check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468500/image-react-native-not-working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675100/image-uri-wont-load-when-using-setstate

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <Image source={(rowData.avatar)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Images cannot use dynamically generated sources. Assuming what you're trying to do is to load an image as part of your package, your code must read:

```
const avatar = require('./path/to/avatar.jpg');
```

Only then you can use `avatar` as your source a follows:

```
rowData = {
    avatar: avatar
}

<Image source={rowData.avatar} />
```

If you know before hands what images are going to be needed in your app, I suggest that you create an asset file in which you add all your hardcoded require, such as:

```
// assets.js
return {
    avatar1: require('./path/to/file.jpg'),
    avatar2: require('./path/to/file.jpg'),
    avatar3: require('./path/to/file.jpg'),
}
```

And then you would construct your `rowData` as follows:

```
import avatars from './assets';

rowData = {
    avatar: avatars['avatar1']
}
```

Where you would likely replace `avatar1` with a variable containing the key pointing to the avatar you're interested in.

Here is an [asset file](https://github.com/FMCorz/pocketgo/blob/master/assets.js) I used for one of my projects.